# Does only 'OnDemand' persistent volumes can be managed by Spark driver? (Spark On Kubernetes)

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark

According to spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/running-on-kubernetes.html#pvc-oriented-executor-pod-allocation): "on-demand PVCs can be owned by driver and reused by another executors during the Spark job’s lifetime with the following options."

Only PVC set as OnDemand and not one I created and provided its name can be reused? It is not clear from the documentation.